# How to Waiting Webbrowser (Window Form) run Script C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one problem when using Webbrowser to control website.

After i load a website

```
webBrowser.Navigate(pageURL);
                while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

This website have 2 Select list

Select Distrcit ||||||||||||||||||||||

Select Ward ||||||||||||||||||||||||||

First i select District

```
elementDistrict.Children()[2].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
elementDistrict.InvokeMember("onchange");
```

and Sleep (warting for "Select Ward" load data)

```
Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

after that, i select Ward

```
elementDistrict.Children()[3].SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
```

I can not select a ward because "Select Ward" data is not load yet.

HTML page before select district:

```
<select id="cboDistrictPost" onchange="ChangeDistrictPost($(this).val())" class="select" tabindex="5">
    <option value="1">District 1 </option>
    <option value="2">District 2 </option>
</select>

<select id="cboWardPost" class="select" tabindex="5">
    <option value="-1">---Select Ward---</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are setting the thread to sleep that the web browser is on. If you set the UI thread to sleep the web browser will not continue loading.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this case, do you have any suggestion for me?